# Add Microphone Access/Recognition in cefSharp

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, cefsharp, microphone

The following code has been done using vb.net

```
Public chromeBrowser As ChromiumWebBrowser

Public Sub InitializeChromium()
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()

    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream")
    ' Initialize cef with the provided settings
    Try
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    ' Create a browser component
    chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html")
    ' Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
    Me.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser)
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub
```

I would like to know how to enable microphone access in cefsharp web browser

Comment: What version are you using? Try https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/51/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L53

Comment: am using ver#51 and also try above example but it shows me errors
kindly provide me a working demo as help if you want

Comment: Use the example provided as part of the project source and uncomment out the line linked.

Comment: i tried to run that example but not works recieve errors kindly provide me a  demo if you want

Comment: else i add here the list of that errors

Comment: Have you confirmed that it works using `Chrome`? Other users report that it works fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630903/how-to-make-getusermedia-method-works-on-chromium-web-browser-inside-winforms

Comment: yes it works on google chrome but not work on my vb.net form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream")
```

...try this

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
```

Comment: Using the same key for both and passing in 1 have worked in the past, if you've tested the first and it wasn't working then please update to include which version you are seeing the behavior with.

Comment: i'ts possible emulate this in WebBrowser on VB.NET? Basically enable microphone access?