# How to make getUserMedia() method works on Chromium Web browser inside WinForms application?

Tags: winforms, webrtc, chromium, getusermedia, cefsharp

I'm trying to get access to my webcam from my WinForms application using Chromium webbrowser control, to do that I installed my HTML file - which is shown below - to a server (on my machine) then I tried to navigate to it from my application but the error callback of getUserMedia() method was executed showing "Permission Denied Error", on the other hand it's working fine if I tried to navigate to it directly from chrome. So, is there anyone could know what causes this error ?

```js
// client.js file

(function () {
    window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
        alert(errorMsg, ',URL: ' + url + ' ,Line: ' + lineNumber);        
        return true;
    }
    })();

function hasUserMedia() {
    //check if the browser supports the WebRTC 
    return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
       navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

}

if (hasUserMedia()) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
       || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    
    //enabling video and audio channels 
    navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');

        //inserting our stream to the video tag     
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }, function (err) { alert(err.name + " : " + err.message  ); });
} else {
    alert("WebRTC is not supported");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay></video>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome moved to requiring https for getUserMedia a while back. That change seems to be getting in the way here, given the error.

Comment: Thanks for the replay @jib, I have found the solution, since I'm using chromium web browser control to render my HTML pages (using CefSharp library) , I should have sent a command line argument to enable the media stream as follows:
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream");
Cef.Initialize(settings) ;